# nginx can't handle proxy_ssl_name in form of ipv6?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ipv6

I set 'proxy_ssl_name' as an ipv6 address like '2620:128:1021:1111::11' and found nginx will cut the ipv6 address with colon and only pass the first part '2620'. Looks like nginx handles the part after the first colon as port information. But it's not true for ipv6 address.
Does anybody know how to resolve this issue? Could nginx handle 'proxy_ssl_name' in form of ipv6 correctly? Thanks!
BTW, my nginx version is 1.20.1

Comment: `proxy_ssl_name` sets the SNI. SNI must be a domain name, not an IP address. It is unclear what you want to achieve here in the first place - if you want to use an IP as target use it in the URL of `proxy_pass`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Since we don't have domain name for a specified server, only have IP address, we set 'proxy_ssl_name' as IP address. This looks OK for IPv4 but has mentioned issue for IPv6. Do I have to require a domain name for the server, or is there any other solution?

Comment: Again:  It is unclear what you want to achieve here in the first place - __if you want to use an IP as target use it in the URL of proxy_pass__